# Install (native) Ruby Gems with specific architecture on macos

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Is it possible to install a **native** Ruby Gem with a different architecture from the local one?

I am working on macos Monterey with apple silicon (`arm64-darwin21`) but I would like to compile for `x86_64-apple-darwin` to avoid having to use a different laptop.

For my C library I use the `-target x86_64-apple-darwin` option with `clang` and it works. I have tried with

```
gem install ruby_clipper --platform x86_64-apple-darwin -v 6.2.1.5.2
```

but it seems to be ignored. If I check with `lipo -info` I get

```
Non-fat file: path/to/clipper.bundle is architecture: arm64
```

Comment: Its `--platform PLATFORM` not `--platform=PLATFORM`. `gem install numo-linalg --platform x86_64-apple-darwin`. https://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/

Comment: Getting the same result. The architecture of the bundle is still `arm64`. I have updated the question with a simpler gem as an example

Comment: Hmm, maybe try to run the command with the `ARCHFLAGS` environmental variable set? `ARCHFLAGS=x86_64-apple-darwin gem install ruby_clipper`.

Comment: I unistalled it and verified that the `bundle` was not there  before reinstalling with the flag. Unfortunately, same result.

Comment: You can also specify it in your gemfile - but that setting shouldn't matter if you're installing via the gem command and not bundler.

Comment: @max I am using `rbenv` in case it is important.

Comment: @max also I noticed that in the generated `Makefile` there is a line `arch_hdrdir = /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/include/ruby-2.7.0/arm64-darwin21`. This folder exists, but there is no corresponding folder for x86_64. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. I don't really know how to fix it though without editing the makefile.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the help. At least now I know for sure!